# MYSQL Join help. Get results based on number of comments in seperate comments table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

Beginner here! I am trying to write a query that will select the 3 most commented on results from a "results" table the comments are stored in a seperate "comments" table.

```
results
 - id  
 - title    
 - body   
 - etc
 - etc

comments
 - id  
 - result_id
 - user_id
 - timestamp
 - comment
```

So I need to select all from results and order by the amount of matches between results.id and comments.result_id but I don't really know where to start!

Thanks a lot for the help, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but you can do something like that

```
SELECT  r.id  ,r.title, r.body
FROM results r INNER JOIN (SELECT result_id, count(id) cnt FROM comments GROUP BY result_id) c
ON r.id = c.result_id
ORDER by c.cnt DESC
```

Comment: Please use proper join syntax when posting answers.  (Replace the "," in the from with "join" and change the "where" to "on".)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the hint. It was too fast to think about it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id) AS comment_count FROM results r
LEFT JOIN comments c ON r.id=c.result_id
GROUP BY result_id ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: You probably want to include the results_id in the SELECT clause.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
SELECT r.id, COUNT(r.id) AS comment_count 
FROM results r 
INNER JOIN comments c 
ON results.id = c.result_id 
GROUP BY r.id 
ORDER BY comment_count DESC
```

You join the two tables where the id of the result is the same as the referenced result_id from the comments table. Then you group the rows by result_id to remove duplicates. The `COUNT()` function sums up the grouped rows and displays the number of them.

Then just sort the result based on the generated comment count.

You could use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as well, then you would get **all results** that have no comments as well. If you want this or not depends on your needs.

*For a description of SQL joins, check out [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join)*